# Radio Buttons Include Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

EDIT** Bouchaala Sabri Answer worked perfectly

I am having a problem with some jquery that i am trying to include into my page. For some reason its not working. not sure if the script is wrong or if jquery is being pulled in correctly.

Its basically a script that lets a user choose one option from the top three radio buttons, one option from the second lot of three, but if any of the bottom three are checked the top 6 will be unchecked if they have previouslly been checked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $yearstages = $('input[name="keystage1yr2"],input[name="keystage1yr1"]');
    $savestages = $('input[name="keystage1save"]');
    $('#radios').on('change', 'input', function() {
        if (this.name == "keystage1save") {
            $yearstages.filter('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $savestages.filter('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>



<div id="radios">
<p>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr1" value="Paper" /> <span>&#163;25</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr1" value="CD" /> <span>&#163;25 excl VAT</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr1" value="Paper & CD" /> <span>&#163;40 excl VAT</span>
</p>
<p>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr2" value="Paper" /> <span>&#163;25</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr2" value="CD" /> <span>&#163;25 excl VAT</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr2" value="Paper & CD" /> <span>&#163;40 excl VAT</span>
</p>
<p>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1save" value="Paper" /> <span>&#163;47.50</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1save" value="CD" /> <span>&#163;47.50 excl VAT</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1save" value="Paper & CD" /> <span>&#163;75 excl VAT</span>
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should never forget to wrap your code in

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the following

```
$('#radios').on('change', 'input', function() {
    if (this.name == "keystage1save") {
        $yearstages.filter('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $savestages.filter('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

into `$(function() {...})`. Place your code instead of dots. This code is executed after a page has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is executed before DOM is loaded. Make sure to wrap your code like this:

```
$(function(){
  $yearstages = $('input[name="keystage1yr2"],input[name="keystage1yr1"]');
    $savestages = $('input[name="keystage1save"]');
    $('#radios').on('change', 'input', function() {
        if (this.name == "keystage1save") {
            $yearstages.filter('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $savestages.filter('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

This will execute your code after the DOM is loaded.