# Radio buttons uncheck/check

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have a form which is made up of radio buttons. The link is here http://jsfiddle.net/CUTnY/2/

You can see in the result box there are grey headings and some radio buttons under each header. I am trying, which i am very close, to only let a user select one radio button from each row (which works) but as you can see the bottom row of radio buttons under some headings (some there are 3) are to bulk buy you can see these by looking for any of the rows which in the description have the words "save".

At the moment each set of radio buttons under each heading works correctly example the top 3 rows of radio buttons you can select one from each of the top two rows and if you choose one from the "save" row the top two will deselect. But if you then go to the next set of radio buttons and play around with these (if the user has selected "save" form the top options) that option will dissaper?

Basically each set of radio buttons under each grey heading has to in no way affect the other sets which for some reason they are doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radio Buttons Include Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573410/radio-buttons-include-jquery)

Comment: No that was to get the jquery working this is completley seperate issue, so i have to open another question.

Comment: you can use $('input[name*="rfwpyr"]') instead of copy and paste.

Comment: @eureka sorry i dont understand what you mean?

Comment: $('input[name*="rfwpyr"]') instead of $('input[name="rfwpyr1,2,3,4,5"]')

Comment: @eureka i cant seem to incoporate that to get it to work, alos i can not really see how that would help the problem could you help me out a bit more?

Comment: @Matt it doesn't help your problem, but he's just saying to make it simpler. I think your problem lies in `$('.style5').on('change'` and using `this`.

Comment: So maybe if i change $('.style5') so its specific to each set of radio buttons under each heading?

Comment: @Matt yes, but with what you have, i don't think it will work. You have class="radio", so you can do .radio instead, but like i said i don't think that will quite work either. I'm still trying to parse your html and code (I hate tables).

Comment: @Matt you have a lot of redundant code, I'm thinking you can minimize this to maybe using a map instead.

Comment: @Matt i hate tabels to :(. Just figuerd it out i think thanks for all your help though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because anytime you make a selection, .style5 has about 10 handlers that are being called at the same time for input change.

```
//You have 10 of these declared, that all fire at the same time anytime you click on an input that is a descended of a td with class style5

$('.style5').on('change', 'input', function() {
    if (this.name == "keystage1save") {
        $yearstages.filter('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $savestages.filter('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

You need to sectionalize them by using different classes.

Comment: Thanks just figuerd that out :)